# ssh key fingerprint error when trying to switch heroku accounts

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

i often need to switch heroku accounts and use a script which does the following:

```
heroku keys:clear && rm ~/.heroku/credentials && heroku list
```

after which i need to enter my credentials for the account i want to switch to:

```
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: fake@gmail.com
Password: 
Uploading ssh public key /Users/fake/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
!   Fingerprint already exists. Please use one ssh key per Heroku account
```

unfortunatelly i can´t get passed this error.

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

remove the heroku credentials

rm ~/.heroku/credentials

And then upload the key manually

heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/otheraccount.pub

Enter your Heroku credentials and thats it!!

Answer (score 2):

Dont use the same ssh key for mutiple accounts. Please use one ssh key for one account.

For more info to fix this problem you can refer to http://martyhaught.com/articles/2010/12/14/managing-multiple-heroku-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

strangely enough i could solve the problem with:
clearing the keys, deleting credentials switching to other accounts and back again.